# WPF Image External Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, image, external, resources

I have a custom control library with a resouce dictionary that references an image in the same custom control library.

I then have a WPF application with a refernce to the custom control library which contains a resouce dictionary with a style the utilizes the image.

When I try to use the style from the external resouce I get an error telling me it can't find the image referenced in the style.

I have a sample solution made that I can send anyone who needs it, but I am hoping there is someone out there who just knows the answer...

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is what I found...
If you have an external resouce dictionary with a style:

```
<Style x:Key="Arrow" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Height="20">
        <Image Source="/Images/RightArrow.png" />
      </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

and the image is in the Images folder of the external assembly the above source reference works just fine when you are in your development environment, but once you reference the assembly the relative path to the RightArrow.png is lost to the referencing WPF App.  So the answer is to use the following for the source:

```
        <Image Source="/Skin;component/Images/RightArrow.png" />
```

Note the pick URI instead of the relative path.  This assures that the referencing application knows where to really find the image.

Comment: Just as a side note you can also do something like:
<ImageSource x:Key="RightArrow">/Skin;component/Images/RightArrow.png />
and then your Image would look like this:
<Image Source="{StaticResource RightArrow} />

Answer (score 0):

When you add the image to your project in VS, it has a property called "Copy to Output Directory".  Set its value to "Always copy" or "Copy if newer".  Then rebuild.  I'll bet that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks bpayne you are right, that does work.  

Not to be too picky but I don't want a bunch of images in my output directory and I want to be able to redistribute the skin as a single library as opposed to a dll and a bunch of images.